# Python, trouble getting embedded video url

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Ok,  I have been scratching my head on this for way too long.  I am trying to retrieve the url for an embedded video on a web page using Beautiful Soup and requests modules in Python 2.7.6.  I inspect the html in chrome and I can see the url to the video but when I get the page using requests and use Beautiful Soup I can't find the "video" node.  From looking at the source it looks like the video window is a nested html document.  I have searched all over and can't find out why I can't retrieve this.  If anyone could point me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it.  Thanks.

here is the url to one of the videos:

http://www.growingagreenerworld.com/episode125/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that there is an `iframe` with the `video` tag inside which is loaded asynchronously in the browser.

Good news is that you can simulate that behavior by making an additional request to the `iframe` URL passing the current page URL as a `Referer`.

Implementation:

```
import re

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'http://www.growingagreenerworld.com/episode125/'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.115 Safari/537.36'}

with requests.Session() as session:
    session.headers = headers

    response = session.get(url)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content)

    # follow the iframe url
    response = session.get('http:' + soup.iframe['src'], headers={'Referer': url})
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content)

    # extract the video URL from the script tag
    print re.search(r'"url":"(.*?)"', soup.script.text).group(1)
```

Prints:

```
http://pdl.vimeocdn.com/43109/378/290982236.mp4?token2=1424891659_69f846779e96814be83194ac3fc8fbae&aksessionid=678424d1f375137f
```

Comment: I'm getting an error:  `response = session.get('http:' + soup.iframe['src'], headers={'Referer': url})
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`